# Reading/interpreting datasheet

Tags: mosfet, diodes, datasheet, delay

I am currently researching active (synchronous) rectification and I came across interesting controller by Texas Instruments, [LM74670-Q1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm74670-q1.pdf). It basically turns N-channel MOSFET into diode (with much smaller voltage drop, of course). In chapter 7.4., it is written that solution works like conventional diode in 2% of time, while the other 98% it behaves like MOSFET with lower voltage drop. However, I would like to know the delay before MOSFET is activated or how much time is its internal diode conducting. Is it possible to get this info from the datasheet?

Comment: That's not a synchronous rectifier.  It's actually a variation on my patent for ideal diodes.  The earlier patents, by Jansen, didn't work.  It's interesting, because a lawsuit against Raspberry PI, is about to launch for using my patent and TI may not be far behind.  There are several parts made by TI that actually copy the advertisement of what their circuit does directly from my patent description.  [Here's the patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US8232829). The key difference is that the circuit is not based on time, but bias voltage.

Comment: I never said this is a synchronous rectifier. Your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @jurij: Look again at the first line of your question.

Comment: @user2133679: TI is not infringing on your patent. Your design requires a separate power supply, while the TI part uses a charge pump running off of the Vf of the MOSFET body diode.

Comment: Dave, I didn't specify that the power supply had to be separate in the claims.  Raspberry PI made a similar mistake.  There is also a zener diode symbol inside the mosfet of my patent, and a separate one in a different location.  If you know what modulation of a parasitic avalanche diode, AKA zener diode is, you know that even if TI isn't infringing on my patent ... many people who add regular mosfets to TI's part with an intrinsic diode likely ARE.  The parasitic diode that is the body diode happens to show the zener/avalanche effect.  The patent office considers them the same.

Comment: @user2133679 Claims 1, 13, and 17 of US8232829 say that the zener is connected between the second transistor (which is connected to the output) and the current mirror. Neither the MOSFET's body diode nor the TVS diode at the output of the Pi fit these claims.

Comment: You're a great example of exactly why people get sued over patents.  Only one claim needs to be violated to prosecute. Remember, the artwork doesn't determine the patent.  The artwork only shows one instance of how the claims can be interpreted. The artwork must disclose a "working" circuit for the patent to be valid.  I'm not the owner of the patent, I'm only the inventor.  ?Foley and Lardner? will prosecute because R3 is one side of the current mirror, attached to ground & TVS, attached to U14's transistor, which is the other side of the TVS.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, yes, all of that is in the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me and tell me where to look? Thanks.

Comment: Could you help me understand how to calculate the delay? Chapter 8.1.3.2 has the calculation that I do not understand ... let's say if frequency of AC voltage is 50Hz, how can be MOSFET ON time 1.21 seconds? What do those 1.21 seconds mean? MAX ON MOSFET time for 1uF capacitor?